# Visual Studio 2015 Community or 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-c++

Some time ago, students were offered Visual Studio 2013 Professional through [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com). Now the offer has been replaced by Visual Studio 2015 Community. Should I remove the professional in favour of the new offer?

Answer (score 1):

I have both installed on my machine and they both work well seamlessly...

Compatibility with previous releases

Windows Store app projects for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 can be opened in Visual Studio 2015. *As per microsoft* :[Visual Studio Compatability](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx)

You can install and use Visual Studio 2015 alongside Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012. It can also be installed on top of Visual Studio 2015 RC without having to uninstall RC.

.NET 4.6 is a highly compatible in-place update of .NET 4, .NET 4.5, .NET 4.5.1, and .NET 4.5.2. See Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework for more information on .NET compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**; you should **install** the Visual Studio **2015** Community since it has newer features and new project templates. You can use .NET 5 in 2015 much easier that in 2013.

You **don't** have to **uninstall** the **2013** Professional you can keep it and have **both** installed side by side.

Hope that helps!